# Relative approximation of morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $S$ a qcqs scheme, and let $f : X := \varprojlim_j X_j \to S$ be an inverse limit of qcqs schemes $f_j : X_j \to S$ with affine transition maps.

Suppose $f$ is (P). Is $f_j$ also (P) for all $j$ large enough?

(1) P = flat;

(2) P = finite;

(3) P = quasi-finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No (in general).
Let $A$ be a non-zero ring and let $S = \mathrm{Spec}(A[T]/(T^2))$. Let $M$ be a free $A$-module of infinite rank, viewed as an $A[T]/(T^2)$-module via the section $A[T]/(T^2) \rightarrow A$ which sends $T$ to $0$.

Take $X_j =  \mathrm{Spec}(A[T]/(T^2) \oplus M)$, where $m^2 = 0$ for any $m \in M$, with  affine transition maps given by the composition
$$
A[T]/(T^2) \oplus M \rightarrow A[T]/(T^2)  \rightarrow A[T]/(T^2) \oplus M.
$$
The limit $X \rightarrow S$ is an isomorphism, hence satisfies $(1),(2),(3)$, while each $X_j$ satisfies none of the properties $(1),(2),(3)$.